# How can I get Intent in a service?

Tags: android

I have this intent:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Servicio.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_BT_DEVICE, btDevice);
getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
```

But for some reason, in the service with this code:

```
btDevice = (BluetoothDevice) params.getExtras().get(MainActivity.EXTRA_BT_DEVICE); 
// btDevice = getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_BT_DEVICE)
```

It says the intent is null, but it isn't null on the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind service to activity for access service methods. Using service object you can call service method and pass value from activity to service.
Write this code in activity-

```
 Servicio mService;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, Servicio.class);
    bindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mService = null;
}

private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder rawBinder) {
        mService = ((Servicio.LocalBinder) rawBinder).getService();

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
        ////     mService.disconnect(mDevice);
        mService = null;
    }
};
```

mService is the object of your service class using this you can pass value to service.

Write this in service class

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public Servicio getService() {
        return Servicio.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to send value to the service, I just want to send the object

Comment: using this way you can send everything which you want including BluetoothDevice

Comment: It is all red, some variable, library i must create before¿?

Comment: are you sure you write this code in activity?
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder rawBinder) {
        mService = ((Servicio.LocalBinder) rawBinder).getService();

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
        ////     mService.disconnect(mDevice);
        mService = null;
    }
};

Comment: Yes, anyway, I want to use the code i show you, this code doesn't seem to work with my project